# How to implement while loop in SQL procedures?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am pretty new to SQL procedures. I have a requirement where I need to gather weekly report based on the date passed.

I have 2 columns say name and timestamp.

Now the report gives the details of how many times the name is found in a week of day for the whole week.

I am able to get it for daily but not sure show to capture it for weekly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add table structure, example data, expected output and what you have tried.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Am using MSSQL. Those are the only columns in my table. Name and Timestamp.

Comment: What is the data type of Timestamp? Datetime?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the RDBMS.  However, what you want to do is readily supported in a SQL query:

```
select name,
       sum(case when timestamp "during the time period" then 1 else 0 end)
from t
group by name
```

I put "during the time period" in quotes, because this varies by database and you didn't really clarify what you mean.  The suggestion, though, is to do this in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have used almost same query. But they are giving me distinct results based on time. say for example <br> name,count,timestamp1(of same date) and name,count,timestamp2(of same date). But need the data on same date to be grouped. makes sense?